# Google Analytics Tracking on button click (in-page search)

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, universal-analytics

How can I incorporate Google Analytics In-Page search tracking via my following search code (which is set to google search "KEYWORDS site:MYDOMAIN.com"?

The issue I face is that hitting Enter causes the user to immediately jump to google for the search query. I've seen some bits and pieces of using [hitCallback](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#hitCallback) but I'm unsure of how to implement this on a page of this setup.

```
<form action="http://www.google.com/search" name="searchbox";
method="get" id="searchform" class="form-search">;
<input type="hidden" name="hl" value="en" />;
<input type="hidden" name="ie" value="ISO-8859-1" />;
<input type="hidden" name="sitesearch" id="s" value="MYDOMAIN.com" />;
<input maxlength="256" size="40" name="q" class="search" value="" />;
</form>
```

I'm aware I can't use the traditional in-page search offered by the new Universal Analytics but I don't see why there shouldn't be a way to, on submit, submit to GA prior to leaving my domain for the google search page. And in thinking through things I believe one could redirect to another page, submit the GA, then redirect to google but I'd certainly like to minimize my requests and come up with a straightforward solution.

Comment: I think what would be ideal would be to submit the search to the current page first, then redirect the user to the appropriate google search page. This way, I can still use GA's built-in Site Search functionality, without having to create a separate tracking event for search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <script>

    $("#searchform").submit(function (event) {



        event.preventDefault(); // cancel default behavior

        var searchTerms = $('input[name=q]').val();
        searchTerms = searchTerms.replace(" ", "+");
        console.debug(searchTerms);
        ga('send', {
            'hitType': 'pageview',
            'page': "http://MYDOMAIN.com/search?hl=en&ie=ISO-8859-1&sitesearch=MYDOMAIN.com&q=" + searchTerms,
            'title': 'Google Search'
        });
        setTimeout(function () {
            window.location.href = "http://google.com/search?hl=en&ie=ISO-8859-1&sitesearch=MYDOMAIN.com&q=" + searchTerms;
        }, 500);

    });

     </script>
```

The best method I found to achieving a pseudo in-site-search (delivered via google search) despite visiting an external domain was to cause a fake page view prior to redirecting to the correct search page. I inserted a half-second delay to ensure the page view was sent prior to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the `action` from the form and set it with jQuery after putting a timeout on it to let the GATC fire. Something like this:

```
$('#searchform').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    window.setTimeout(function(){
        if (typeof _gaq != 'undefined') {
            _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Search', 'value', 'paramX', 'valueY', false]);
        }                                        

        $('#searchform').attr('action', 'http://www.google.com/search');

    },1000);

});
```

Comment: This may work in theory, but in a quick test the page refreshes and I end up with a bit like `http://www.MYDOMAIN.com/test.php?hl=en&ie=ISO-8859-1&sitesearch=MYDOMAIN.com&q=test`... As in, it's not redirecting to google with the appended string but instead doing it locally. Probably because the action would need to exist prior to submission? And wouldn't this not work 100% of the time really contingent on timing of the event firing as well as the event being properly pushed?

Comment: @Bernard Try adding a `e.preventDefault();` as the first line inside the function. Sorry, I can't test it entirely but hopefully this will help.

Comment: Thanks for your help @crmpicco. I thought to try that but it's still causing a quick refresh in addition to submitting the string to the current page.